# Relationship between determinant and integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, matrices, determinant

According to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/221542/exchange-determinant-and-integral-of-a-matrix-valued-function), there exists a relationship between determinant and integral, as follows:

$$
\frac{1}{\operatorname{vol} [M]}\int _M \det(B+\nabla \phi)=\det B
$$

Then it goes to say that this applies in the case "[...] if $A$ is a constant $B$ plus the Jacobian matrix of a compactly supported field $\phi$ (for instance if $M$ has no boundary), then the integral and the determinant do commutte".

Can anyone unpack this relation, perhaps with an example or a link with more information? For instance, what is $M$, what is the volume of $M$? Does it work with any matrix $B$? What does $B$ being a constant plus the Jacobian matrix and does it relate to the expression $B+\nabla \phi$?

---

Edit:

My interest is to attack the problem in the other direction as that of the linked question; that is to start with the determinant of a matrix $B$ and then convert it to an equivalent "integral-form" using the equality above. Can $B$ be an arbitrary $n\times n$ matrix, or does it have special restrictions?

Then, it appears that it suffices that I introduce an arbitrary field $\nabla \phi$ and define the integral with respect to this field, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a sphere $M$ with standard metric and spherical coordinate chart ($\varphi$, $\theta$). Let's have a field $\phi=(\cos\theta, 0)$, then its Jacobian matrix:
$$
\nabla\phi = \begin{pmatrix}0&-\sin\theta\\0&0\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Take some constant $B=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\-1&2\end{pmatrix}$, then $\det(B+\nabla\phi)=3-\sin\theta$.

Consider integral:
$$
\int_M \det(B+\nabla\phi) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}(3-\sin\theta)\cos\theta d\theta d\varphi = 12\pi = \underbrace{\mathop{\mathrm{vol}}(M)}_{4\pi}\underbrace{\det B}_{3}.
$$

where $\mathrm{vol}(M)=\int_M1$ is a total volume (in that case area) of a manifold $M$.

Comment: You are correct to assume you can take any matrix B and any field $\phi$

Comment: But if the entries of $B$ are functions of $\theta$ and $\varphi$, then does it still work?

Comment: No. As it was pointed in your link “constant $B$” which means it doesn't depend on the position in manifold.